# Can I use #undef this way?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c-preprocessor

I want to get some settings I store in the registry, and if they differ from a `#define` I want to redefine it, could I do it this way?:

```
#define DEFINED_X "testSetting"

void LoadConfig()
{
    regConfigX = some value previusly stored in the registry;
    if(regConfigX!=DEFINED_X)
    {
        #undef DEFINED_X
        #define DEFINED_X regConfigX
    }
}
```

I tought `#define` was used only when compiling, would this code work when running the compiled exe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, use a static variable to store the value of DEFINED_X.

Answer (score 1):

No.  `#define` and `#undef` are *preprocessing directives*; they are evaluated before the source code is compiled.

You need to use a variable for this, not a macro.

Answer (score 1):

`#define` and `#undef` occur before your source code even hits the compiler. Anything to do with `#define`s can't happen at runtime.

You should check out the Boost preprocessor library, too.